# How to see XML output of SOAP request in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, web-services, model-view-controller, soap

I am new to Spring SOAP requests. I want to see the final XML output of the SOAP request which includes SOAP header and SOAP envelop.

While debugging I reached up to this piece of code

```
sendSourceAndReceiveToResult(partnerURI, source,
    new WebServiceMessageCallback() {

        public void doWithMessage(WebServiceMessage message)
        throws IOException, TransformerException {

            StringSource mefHeaderSource = new StringSource(
                header);

            SoapHeader soapHeader = ((SoapMessage) message)
                .getSoapHeader();

            Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory
                .newInstance().newTransformer();

            transformer.transform(mefHeaderSource,
                soapHeader.getResult());

        }
    }, result);
```

I suspect here I can see somewhere the output XML SOAP request by putting some logger but I am not sure I am correct. I tried searching for it but in all the posts available on google nothing is clear.

The issue which we are debugging is client is not able to see SOAP header in the SOAP request.

Answer (score 5):

Make sure to use Commons Logging version 1.1 or higher.

To log all server-side messages, simply set the org.springframework.ws.server.MessageTracing logger to level **DEBUG** or **TRACE**. 
On the debug level, only the payload root element is logged; on the TRACE level, the entire message content. If you only want to log sent messages, use the org.springframework.ws.server.MessageTracing.sent logger; 
or org.springframework.ws.server.MessageTracing.received to log received messages.

On the client-side, similar loggers exist: org.springframework.ws.client.MessageTracing.sent and org.springframework.ws.client.MessageTracing.received.

Here is an example log4j.properties configuration, logging the full content of sent messages on the client side, and only the payload root element for client-side received messages. On the server-side, the payload root is logged for both sent and received messages:

```
log4j.rootCategory=INFO, stdout
log4j.logger.org.springframework.ws.client.MessageTracing.sent=TRACE
log4j.logger.org.springframework.ws.client.MessageTracing.received=DEBUG

log4j.logger.org.springframework.ws.server.MessageTracing=DEBUG

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%p [%c{3}] %m%n
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but in which this logs will be printed means what will be the file name...

Comment: can you take it too a chat here in stackoverflow so I can explain you broadly!!!!

Comment: The above log 4j configuration should be written in your log4j.properties file.                                                                          Apache log4j provides Appender objects which are primarily responsible for printing logging messages to different destinations such as consoles, files, sockets, NT event logs, etc.                                   So here ConsoleAppender writes its output to either System.err or System.out with System.err being the default target.

Comment: your logger destinations can be either console or any file. You can read about log4j appenders before trying this.

Answer (score 0):

from spring documentation for `SoapEnvelopeLoggingInterceptor`

> SOAP-specific EndpointInterceptor that logs the complete request and
>   response envelope of SoapMessage messages. By default, request,
>   response and fault messages are logged, but this behaviour can be
>   changed using the logRequest, logResponse, logFault properties

you can enable this interceptor by adding

```
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:sws="http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services" .../>

      <sws:interceptors>
        <bean class="org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.interceptor.SoapEnvelopeLoggingInterceptor"/>
      </sws:interceptors>

      <sws:static-wsdl ..../>
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. where to add this piece of code and how to see the messgae. We are just testing it for a dummy URL.

Comment: this bean should be defined for the same container where ws endpoints are. log messages would be tracked by logger, so just add this bean, configure needed properties and track messages in main log appenders

Comment: The full package name should be org.springframework.ws.soap.server.endpoint.interceptor