# Visualise soap request

Tags: java, spring-boot, soap

I am using spring boot framework to generate a soap request to consume the soap service.
Using SOAP-UI/ Postman, I can be able to send the request in xml format as specified in service wsdl.
But, I am generating soap request body my marshalling the java object and sending it through spring application.
Is there any way to see/visualise the intermediate request in XML format in this case ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to see XML output of SOAP request in Spring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35288164/how-to-see-xml-output-of-soap-request-in-spring)

Comment: I tried them, but got no output representing the xml format of soap message.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.